# How can i print a list contents in a stderr statement in python

Tags: python

Here is the scenario:

I want to be able to print the C Style statement:

```
print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args)
```

either inside the function, or in `__main__`

but I am getting Exception :

```
print >> sys.stderr, ("%m_args[1] does not exist"%m_args[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re, os, sys, jira, subprocess
from optparse import OptionParser
import warnings
from collections import namedtuple

global m_args

def verify_commit_text(tags):
    for line in tags:
        if re.match(r'[^\NO-TIK]',line):
            return False
        elif re.match(r'[^\NO-REVIEW]', line):
            return False
        elif re.match(r'[a-zA-Z]+-\d+', line):
            # Validate the JIRA ID
            m = re.search("([a-zA-Z]+-\d+)",line)
            m_args = m.group(1)
            m_args = [m_args]
            print 'm_args'
            print m_args
            print type(m_args)
            if CheckForJiraIssueRecord(m_args):
                return False
            else:
                #warnings.warn("%s does not exist"%m_args)
                print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args)
                return True
        else:
            return True

def CheckForJiraIssueRecord(my_args):
    # turn off stdout
    #sys.stdout = open(os.devnull)
    #sys.stderr = open(os.devnull)
    com = jira.Commands()
    logger = jira.setupLogging()
    jira_env = {'home':os.environ['HOME']}
    command_name = "cat"
    server = "http://jira.server.com:8080/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl"
    options = namedtuple('Options', 'user password')('user','password')
    jira.soap = jira.Client(server)
    jira.start_login(options, jira_env, command_name, com, logger)
    issue = com.run(command_name, logger, jira_env, my_args)
    if issue:
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    commit_text_verified = verify_commit_text(os.popen('hg tip --template "{desc}"'))
    if commit_text_verified:
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print >> sys.stderr, ('[obey the rules!]')
        print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args[0])
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Well clearly since `m_args[1]` doesn't exist, trying to access it raises an `IndexError` when you try to access it because it doesn't exist!  What exactly do you want to print out?

Comment: from the 3 lines:
 m = re.search("([a-zA-Z]+-\d+)",line)
            m_args = m.group(1)
            m_args = [m_args]
i want to printout "m-args"

Comment: sorry that was just a small experiment, replacing [1] with [0] , otherwise the code matches if i use print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args)
in __main__ i get.... [] does not exist

Comment: You really need to go through another Python tutorial or two, and maybe buy a book. Your code it riddled with very basic errors, as well as things like putting parenthesis around an `if` condition, which you don't need to do in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args)
```

from the `verify_commit_text()` function.

Now, look at the line causing the error in `__main__`:

```
print >> sys.stderr, ("%m_args[0] does not exist"%m_args[0])
```

You need to replace the `%m_args[0]` inside the string with `%s`.

Also, you're using two different `m_args` -- you're trying to `print` from the global one, while you made a local version in `verify_commit_text()`. Add `global m_args` to the top of `verify_commit_text()` to get rid of the index error (for the case that your last `elif` regex matched, you'll still get it for the case that you hit the `else` clause.)

You also appear to have other problems. You have a `for` loop in `verify_commit_text()` but you're only ever entering the first iteration, because all of your `if` branches `return`.

You're also sending `sys.stderr` to `os.devnull`, so you won't see anything even if your `print`s work.

Also, you've got your exit condition wrong. You're returning `True` on failure, and then using `exit(0)` if the result was `True` -- change it to `if not commit_text_verified:`

One more thing: `CheckForJiraIssueRecord(m_args)` doesn't have a `return` so it's always returning `None`, so the `if` condition it's in will never be `True` -- you'll always go to the `else`.

Comment: i tried:
<pre>
else:
        print >> sys.stderr, ('[obey the rules!]')
        print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args[0])
        #sys.stdout.writelines(m_args.pop())
        sys.exit(1)
</pre>
but i get Index out of range exception, i think i am missing something obvious
exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qa/jira-test/.hg/check_jira.py", line 55, in <module>
    print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @kamal Read the rest of my answer. You need to add the `global m_args` statement to the top of `verify_commit_text()`, and even then you'll get the `IndexError` if you hit the `else` clause of the `if` because then `m_args` will never be set.

Comment: @kamal Also make sure to read the new line I just added to the end of my post. You appear to have your exit condition backwards. And just spotted another error, added that.

Comment: 1. Added "global m_args" on top of verify_commit_text(tags)
2. in __main__ print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args[0])
3. Dont know how to resolve the if's branches returning, My logic was that 0 is success in Python and any non zero is failure
4. commented out stderr redirection, the reason was if i dont do that then the user will receive lots of irrelevant soap data. Dont know how to resolve this 
5. changed the exit() as:
if __name__ == '__main__':
 if (commit_text_verified):   
 sys.exit(1)
else:
print >> sys.stderr, ("%s does not exist"%m_args[0])
sys.exit(0)

Comment: also have CheckForIssueRecord(my_args) return boolean:
issue = com.run(command_name, logger, jira_env, my_args)
    if issue:
        return True

Comment: @kamal If you still have a continuation / update of the question, _edit it into the question_ with the updated code (properly formatted using the `{ }` button). I don't know what your problem is at this point.

Comment: @kamal You're still `print`ing in the `else` clause of `__main__` -- so when you `return False` from `verify_commit_text()` -- so if you match either `[^\NO-TIK]` or `[^\NO-REvIEW]`, you're trying to `print` without adding anything to `m_args`.

Comment: @kamal I've answered your original question and provided a bunch of other help, but the entire structure of your program is faulty -- you will still __never get past the first__ `line` of `tags` because you `return` no matter what that line says, and that ends the loop. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com, that site is for that kind of help. This site is for when you have a specific, identifiable, problem or question.